# Mounting Google Cloud Storage volume in GCE instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to mount Google Cloud Storage as a volume in a GCE instance for an application to access?

Answer (score 2):

It is stil work in progress you can try [s3fuse](https://code.google.com/p/s3fuse/)

Do not expect productional reliability just yet,
at least this was my experience about a month ago...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [s3fuse](https://code.google.com/p/s3fuse/) mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15963692/3618671), there are also [gcsfs](https://code.google.com/p/gcsfs/) (based on s3fuse) and [stormfs](https://github.com/benlemasurier/stormfs).

Note that I haven't tried any of them, so I can't speak as to how robust any of these solutions are.

Answer (score 0):

Google has the official [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) FS now. However, it's in the Beta and never will make it to stable release, since there are problems with the performance and stability which cannot be or are very hard to solve.

The performance degrades rapidly if you need to handle many small files. Also, scanning directories with many files (like `find` does) make take hours or days.

We have tried it for the production, but it has I/O errors occasionally. So now, we use it for the maintenance only.